# Can't change locale of report in BI Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

The field of locale is just inactive, and because I can't set locale of my country all dates in report are messed up -1 day.

Answer (score 1):

Your preferences may be inherited from another Oracle product. If this is true for your work environment, you cannot update your preferences from within BI Publisher.

When BI Publisher is integrated with Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition (BI EE), the Report Locale, UI Language, and Time Zone user preferences are set in the Oracle BI EE application. For more information, see "Setting Preferences" in Oracle Fusion Middleware User's Guide for Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition. When you update your BI Publisher preferences in Oracle BI EE, you must start a new BI Publisher HTTP session for these to take effect in the BI Publisher interface.